# Given a vector, get the coordinates of the same vector on a rectangle.

Tags: vectors, circles, coordinate-systems, collision-detection

I have a circle and a known size vector starting from the center of that circle which comes out of a rectangle. My goal is to know the coordinates (x, y) of the vector being located on the rectangle and of the same size as the first vector.

---

Let's see an exemple:

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikb2e.png)

The vector AB comes out of the rectangle, so I would like to know the coordinates of the vector AE of the same size as AB. If this is possible, I would like to get the closest vector (in this case AE but not AG)

Answer (score 0):

Say center of the circle is at the origin $O$.

Radius of the circle = $r$. Lengths of the sides of the rectangle are $c, d \, (c \geq d \geq r)$. $c$ is horizontal sides in your diagram and $d$ is vertical sides.

A position vector $A (a_1,a_2)$ is out of a given rectangle and $OA = \vec{a}$.

You can find points on the rectangle with the magnitude of vector $\vec{a}$, only if

$r \leq |\vec{a}| \leq \sqrt{c^2 + d^2} - r \sqrt2 \, \,$ ($c, d$ are sides of the rectangle).

Say we need to find a position vector $B (b_1, b_2)$ on the perimeter of the rectangle such that $\vec{b} = \vec{a} \, \, (\vec{OB} = \vec{b})$.

Any point on the sides of the rectangle are given by (depending on which side it is)

$(\pm x, r), (-(c-r), \pm y), (\pm x, -(d-r)), (r, \pm y)$.

Equate distance on each side of the rectangle to the magnitude of $|\vec{a}|$ to find the possible points.

For example, $x^2 + r^2 = |\vec{a}|^2$ should give you possible points on the upper horizontal side of the rectangle. Now how do you know this point works or not? Using the constraints for the points to be on the rectangle,

$-(c-r) \leq x \leq r$

$-(d-r) \leq y \leq r$

Once you know the points on the rectangle, you know all possible vector $\vec{b}$.

How do you know which one is closest? Do a dot product and find the angle between them. The lowest angle between them will give you the closest position vector $\vec{B}$ to $\vec{A}$.

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |\vec{a}| \, |\vec{b}| \, \cos \theta$

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't understand `(±x,r),(−(c−r),±y),(±x,−(d−r)),(r,±y)`. How to generate all possible points before checking them ? Thanks

Comment: $x, y$ are variables that you will find equating the distance (magnitude of vector $A$). See one example I gave. Rest are all known as they are radius of the circle and sides of the rectangle. We have assumed center of the circle to be at $(0,0)$ as a reference point.

Comment: But for instance, if I onlywant to treat the upper horizontal case.
1) I check that there are possible points
2) I take `(±x, r)` and resolve `x**2+r**2 = a**2`
3) I get my x easily with `sqrt(a**2 - r**2)` or  `-sqrt(a**2 - r**2)`

But I don't understand how to find y.

My goal is to implement a computer program that solves this.

Comment: if $a \geq r, $ it will resolve for sure. But once you get the values of $x,$ check whether it is in the range or not (I wrote the range in my answer).

Comment: Thanks but with the exemple of my last post, how can I get the y once I have the x ? Sorry but I'm trying to make a program and it's not easy..

Comment: In any case, what is the radius of the circle and what is the dimension of the rectangle? I need that to answer your question. That's not in your diagram.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117042/discussion-between-codingfr-and-math-lover).

Comment: If you can help me in chat, it would be very useful for me